# Read Web.config settings from comma-delimited string

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am reading specific AppSetting key/value pairs in Web.config, using hard-coded values, with the code below.  This works.

```
string[] filteredList = webConfigApp.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Equals("appMode") || x.Equals("loggingMode") || x.Equals("ticketModeCache") || x.Equals("ticketMode")).ToArray();
```

Instead, I would like to read from a comma-separated list that is also in Web.config, for example:

```
<add key="setConfigValues" value="appMode,loggingMode,ticketModeCache,ticketMode,twilioMode,kioskId,kioskPrinterConfig" />
```

I know how to to parse and create a List<> doing something along these lines...

```
List<string> ConfigValues = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setConfigValues"].Split(',').ToList();
```

...but I am not sure how to code the Linq part to include values in the List.

How can I do this?  I tried x.Contains but that does not work (understandably).  I am looking to find AppSetting keys that are in the comma-delimited list.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would transform that into a case insensitive dictionary:

```
var configValues = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setConfigValues"]
    .Split(", ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(
        item => item,
        item => webConfigApp.AppSettings.Settings[item].Value, 
        StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);


if (configValues.ContainsKey("loggingMode"))
{
    // do stuff
}

if (configValues.TryGetValue("loggingMode", out string value) && value == "on")
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: interesting.  i was looking for just the key, then iterate for the values, but this gets the key and the value in the same array. nice!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Select() or Where() methods
For example:

```
List<string> ConfigValues = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setConfigValues"].Split(',').ToList();
ConfigValues.Select(val => val == "x");
```

Comment: txs. your post got me thinking of other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked was much easier than I thought.  This worked for what I was trying to do:

```
string[] filteredList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setConfigValues"].Split(',').ToArray();
```

Specifically, I am using the keys of the "setConfigValues" array to pull the Web.config values, so parsing the comma-delimited string into a string[] is enough.

```
        foreach (string s in filteredList) 
        {
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s, webConfigApp.AppSettings.Settings[s].Value));
        }
```

Comment: compare your code with the result of the code i proposed ;-)